# How can I append a <br> using document.getElementByID?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to append a `<p>` element using DOM to append a stock symbol, and stock price, then go to a new line using `<br>`, but when I run this:

```
for(var i=0; i<stockPrices.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("stockprice").append(stockNames[i]+" ");
    document.getElementById("stockprice").append(stockPrices[i]+" ");
    document.getElementById("stockprice").append("<br>");
}
```

it literally adds the text `<br>` to my "stockprice" element. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: You can use `.innerHTML += "<br />";` instead of `.append()` to add HTML

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know that was possible. Thank you for the help!

Comment: try this. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: @TrevorBollinger also, I would query the DOM before your loop and save the result in a variable, constantly querying the DOM is not very efficient. See CertainPerformance's answer for a better approach

Answer (score 4):

Use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead:

```js
document.body.append('content');
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br>');
document.body.append('more content');
```

I'd recommend against concatenating with the existing `innerHTML` because that will

(1) corrupt existing listeners inside the container, if any, and

(2) force the browser to re-parse the entire contents of the container (in contrast, with `insertAdjacentHTML`, the browser *only* parses/inserts what gets *added*)

Note that you can also save the element in a variable first to avoid repeating yourself:

```
const stockPriceElm = document.getElementById("stockprice");
for(var i=0; i<stockPrices.length; i++){
  stockPriceElm.append(stockNames[i]+" ");
  stockPriceElm.append(stockPrices[i]+" ");
  stockPriceElm.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<br>");
}
```

Or, even better:

```
const stockPriceElm = document.getElementById("stockprice");
for (var i = 0; i < stockPrices.length; i++) {
  stockPriceElm.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', stockNames[i] + " " + stockPrices[i] + " <br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go for [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

```js
function appendContent() {
  document.getElementById("stockprice").innerHTML += "<br>";
  document.getElementById("stockprice").innerHTML += "New Data";
}
```

```html
<p id="stockprice">Initial Content</p>
<button onclick="appendContent()">Append</button>
```